# 100% height divs

Tags: html, css

I feel really stupid for not seeing whats wrong here.

Basically three divs in a row with a container - want all of them to be as high as the container.

Here's a reduced test case:

http://codepen.io/jgclifton/full/mDdpv

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `div.container` an explicit height, and your `div`s will line up perfectly. Currently, it has a height of `auto`, meaning that using `height: 100%` on the child elements has no effect. Setting a height of, say, 200px on the container gives the percentage-based height something to use as a reference.

Comment: Thanks, I was worried this was the problem - trying to avoid fixed heights so I'll see if I can find a clever solution.

Answer (score 1):

Container has height: auto;
If you change it to height: 100px; for exemple, every divs have same height to me.